# Chromium Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated

Tags: 14.04, chromium

I'm having troubles starting Chromium since friday. I have used this laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T540p) with Ubuntu 14.04 32bit for about 3 years and have always used Chromium. When I click on the icon in the Unity bar however, the icon starts flashing like it's going to start but nothing happens. No error code, no window, nothing. I tried starting it from the terminal with `chromium-browser` and get following error tracefile:

```
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000002f5df78
#0 0x0000b46944b3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x0000b4693d77 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x0000b46948ce <unknown>
#3 0x0000b47de410 ([vdso]+0x40f)
#4 0x0000b584999c <unknown>
#5 0x0000b584a758 <unknown>
#6 0x0000b55864b8 <unknown>
#7 0x0000b557ec43 <unknown>
#8 0x0000b5581e02 <unknown>
#9 0x0000afd4501c BrowserContextKeyedServiceFactory::BuildServiceInstanceFor()
#10 0x0000b0410436 KeyedServiceFactory::GetServiceForContext()
#11 0x0000b5581ee6 <unknown>
#12 0x0000b54cea8e <unknown>
#13 0x0000b54cf388 <unknown>
#14 0x0000b6061c1e <unknown>
#15 0x0000b54bb076 <unknown>
#16 0x0000b5627832 <unknown>
#17 0x0000b5627d15 <unknown>
#18 0x0000b21ff6dc content::StoragePartitionImplMap::Get()
#19 0x0000b1ec8619 <unknown>
#20 0x0000b1ec8f57 content::BrowserContext::GetStoragePartition()
#21 0x0000b1ec9177 content::BrowserContext::GetDefaultStoragePartition()
#22 0x0000b5624e4e <unknown>
#23 0x0000b5625734 <unknown>
#24 0x0000b5625af1 <unknown>
#25 0x0000b5626787 <unknown>
#26 0x0000b56269fb <unknown>
#27 0x0000b54bf7c3 <unknown>
#28 0x0000b54c4bfd <unknown>
#29 0x0000b54c4ecc <unknown>
#30 0x0000b60aef30 <unknown>
#31 0x0000b56dd298 <unknown>
#32 0x0000b56de1dc <unknown>
#33 0x0000b1ecbe69 content::BrowserMainLoop::PreMainMessageLoopRun()
#34 0x0000b21f7607 content::StartupTaskRunner::RunAllTasksNow()
#35 0x0000b1ecd4fe content::BrowserMainLoop::CreateStartupTasks()
#36 0x0000b1ed2533 <unknown>
#37 0x0000b1ecb032 content::BrowserMain()
#38 0x0000b25ae6ee <unknown>
#39 0x0000ad548b4b service_manager::Main()
#40 0x0000b25ad240 content::ContentMain()
#41 0x0000b506f047 ChromeMain
#42 0x0000b506d61b <unknown>
#43 0x0000ad694af3 __libc_start_main
#44 0x0000b506ee8e <unknown>
  gs: 00000033  fs: 00000000  es: 0000007b  ds: 0000007b
 edi: b929809c esi: b9297f00 ebp: bff5bde8 esp: bff5bcb0
 ebx: b9297d48 edx: 00000006 ecx: 00000026 eax: bff5be00
 trp: 0000000e err: 00000004  ip: b584999c  cs: 00000073
 efl: 00210282 usp: bff5bcb0  ss: 0000007b
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

I checked if I did any update for chromium, but the only thing I can find is this from two days before it stopped working:

```
2017-06-07 08:43:58 configure chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178 <none>
2017-06-07 08:43:58 status unpacked chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:43:58 status half-configured chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:43:58 status installed chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:43:58 configure chromium-browser:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178 <none>
2017-06-07 08:43:58 status unpacked chromium-browser:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:43:58 status unpacked chromium-browser:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:43:58 status unpacked chromium-browser:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:43:58 status unpacked chromium-browser:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:43:58 status half-configured chromium-browser:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:44:00 status installed chromium-browser:i386 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:44:00 configure chromium-browser-l10n:all 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178 <none>
2017-06-07 08:44:00 status unpacked chromium-browser-l10n:all 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:44:00 status half-configured chromium-browser-l10n:all 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
2017-06-07 08:44:00 status installed chromium-browser-l10n:all 59.0.3071.86-0ubuntu0.14.04.1178
```

I have tried reinstalling Chromium from the software center but that doesn't help. It seems like I'm not the only one with the problem (for instance [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2363203) on the ubuntuforum) but I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed in the new update, Version 59.0.3071.86 (Developer Build)

Comment: I just ran into SEGV_MAPERR in 59.0.3071.109-0ubuntu0.16.04.1289, did you see any commit or bugreport saying that it was fixed in 59.0.3071.86, or did it just fix your instance?

Comment: Your problem was bugreport https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1697496

Comment: My problem is bugreport https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1702407